# How to modify encoding characters through DB2 (v8.2) JDBC URL?

Tags: java, jdbc, db2, character

I use dataX to transfer DB2 data to MySql. The JSON configuration used involves the JDBC URL of DB2. I want to convert the character encoding while extracting DB2 data.

`DB2` version is `v8.2`.

I just use next db2 jdbc url:

`jdbc:db2://192.168.1.117:50000/MyTest01:CHARSET=GBK;`

but the encoding characters set did not work! What's the right way to go?

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to achieve. Normally character set translation is done by the driver automatically based on the database character set and the client locale. The database character set can only be defined when creating the database. Also mention your Db2 version and platform.

Comment: I corrected my problem. I just want to get `DB2 (v8.2) `data through JDBC and modify the character encoding of the data at the same time

Comment: `encoding characters set did not work` - what doesn't work exactly?

Comment: If you export your data to a file, and your program doesn't open the file specifying this encoding in the, let's say, OutputStreamWriter constructor explicitly, try to run your java program as `java -Dfile.encoding=GBK ...`